# How to return file object from google drive download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

I'm new to Rails.

I have a method that downloads a file from google drive and saves it in the local disc. When the file is downloaded, the console returns `nil`, but the file is in the folder.

I need to use this file in my controller, but if the download method is returning `nil` I can't pass it around as an object.

download method:

```
def download
  found = google_files.select { |f| f.id == file_id }
  file_title = found.first.title
  file = session.file_by_title(file_title)
  path = File.join(Backup.base_directory, file_title)
  file.download_to_file("#{path}")
end
```

Controller:

```
def create
  # file_id = params.fetch(:file_id)
  file_id = "0Byyflt8z3jarbm5DZGNNVXZSWjg"
  @backup = DiscourseDownloadFromDrive::DriveDownloader.new(file_id).download
end
```

console output after executing the download method:

```
[...]
Writing chunk (1397 bytes)
Writing chunk (1397 bytes)
Writing chunk (1397 bytes)
Writing chunk (619 bytes)
Success - nil

=> nil
[4] pry(main)>
```

Logger:

```
Rails.logger.debug(">>> @BACKUP >>>: #{@backup.inspect}")

D, [2017-09-07T20:21:24.835450 #7755] DEBUG -- : >>> @BACKUP >>>: nil
```

Any hint on how to proceed with this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What's in your `show` action? Looks like that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: The show action at the moment only includes two Rails.logger.debug statements. I've updated the question, basically `@backup` logs `nil`.

Comment: Throw a `byebug` in after the `file_id` line in your create action and try running `DiscourseDownloadFromDrive::DriveDownloader.new(file_id).download` to see what you get. Guessing the error is when creating the drive downloader

Comment: DiscourseDownloadFromDrive::DriveDownloader.new(file_id).dow‌​nload runs correctly, the issue is that the object it returns is `nil`, even tho it's being saved.

Comment: Are you able to change the `download` method?

Comment: It's the download method from the gem. I'm using download_to_file option from: http://www.rubydoc.info/search/gems/google_drive?q=download

Comment: I know. Can you change the `download` method wich is not from the gem?

Comment: oh, yes, there's no problem with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `download` method always returns nothing but `nil`. That's because the gem's `download_to_file` always returns `nil`.

You shoud change your `download` method for it to return something, that you can use to get the file. I think this method should return the path to the downloaded file.

```
def download
  found = google_files.select { |f| f.id == file_id }
  file_title = found.first.title
  file = session.file_by_title(file_title)
  path = File.join(Backup.base_directory, file_title)
  file.download_to_file("#{path}")
  path
end
```

Now you can use it in the controller:

```
def create
  # file_id = params.fetch(:file_id)
  file_id = "0Byyflt8z3jarbm5DZGNNVXZSWjg"
  file_path = DiscourseDownloadFromDrive::DriveDownloader.new(file_id).download
  @backup = File.open(file_path) # do whatever you want with the file, since now you know how to get it
end
```

Comment: Thanks @chumakoff you've made my day!